# Delete the associated blog posts with user before deleting the respective user in mongodb and nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema, mongoose-middleware

When I am deleting a user, I also want to delete all the associated blog posts with that user. I have used MongoDB's pre() middleware. when it is fired it only sets the postedBy property to null in the post and then MongoDB compass the postedBy is still there along with userId
here is User schema.

```
const crypto = require("crypto");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const Post = require("./post");

const userSchema = mongoose.Schema(
  {
    username: {
      type: String,
      trim: true,
      required: true,
      unique: true,
      index: true,
      lowercase: true,
    },
    name: {
      type: String,
      index: true,
      required: true,
      max: 32,
    },
    email: {
      type: String,
      index: true,
      required: true,
      trim: true,
      unique: true,
    },
    hashed_password: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    role: {
      type: Number,
      default: 0,
    },
    profile: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    photo: {
      data: Buffer,
      contentType: String,
    },
    salt: String,
    resetPassword: {
      data: String,
      default: "",
    },
  },
  { timestamp: true }
);

userSchema
  .virtual("password")
  .set(function (password) {
    this._password = password;
    this.salt = this.makeSalt();
    this.hashed_password = this.encryptPassword(password);
  })
  .get(function () {
    return this._password;
  });
userSchema.methods = {
  authenticate: function (plainText) {
    return this.encryptPassword(plainText) === this.hashed_password;
  },
  encryptPassword: function (password) {
    if (!password) return "";
    try {
      return crypto
        .createHmac("sha1", this.salt)
        .update(password)
        .digest("hex");
    } catch (err) {
      return "";
    }
  },
  makeSalt: function () {
    return Math.round(new Date().valueOf() * Math.random()) + "";
  },
};
userSchema.pre("findByIdAndRemove", function (next) {
  Post.deleteMany({ postedBy: this._id }, function (err, result) {
    if (err) {
      console.log("error");
    } else {
      console.log(result);
    }
  });
  next();
});
module.exports = mongoose.model("User", userSchema);
```

here is Post schema

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const postSchema = new Schema({
  postedBy: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "User",
  },
  title: {
    type: String,
  },
  body: {
    type: String,
  },
  name: {
    type: String,
  },
  photo: {
    data: Buffer,
    contentType: String,
  },
  updated: Date,
  avatar: {
    type: String,
  },
  created: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now,
  },
  comments: [
    {
      postedBy: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        refPath: "onModel",
      },
      text: String,

      created: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now,
      },
    },
  ],
  likes: [
    {
      type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      refPath: "onModel",
    },
  ],
  onModel: {
    type: String,
    enum: ["User", "Imam"],
  },
});
module.exports = mongoose.model("Post", postSchema);
```

this is delete route function

```
exports.userdelete = (req, res) => {
  User.findByIdAndRemove(req.params.id).exec((err, doc) => {
    if (err) {
      return res.status(400).json({
        error: "Something went wrong",
      });
    }
    return res.json({
      message: "User deleted",
    });
  });
};
```

Comment: Have you tried to debug? is the pre function to findbyidandremove actually getting called?

Comment: Did you solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

**You Can follow this code**

> You can use cascade delete in mongoose

```
User.findOne({...}, function(err, customer) {
  Post.remove();
});
```